# pythagorean theorem in 3 Dimensions

Tags: combinatorics, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, polyhedra, exterior-algebra

In Terry Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/23/determinantal-processes/) on determinantal processes, he mentions that:

> From this and the ordinary Pythagorean theorem in the inner product space ${\bigwedge^n {\mathbb R}^N}$, we conclude the multidimensional Pythagorean theorem: the square of the ${n}$-dimensional volume of a parallelopiped in ${{\mathbb R}^N}$ is the sum of squares of the ${n}$-dimensional volumes of the projection of that parallelopiped to each of the ${\binom{N}{n}}$ coordinate subspaces ${\hbox{span}(e_{i_1},\ldots,e_{i_n})}$.

I get this more or less.  That if $\{e_1, e_2, e_3\}$ are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ then $\{e_1 \wedge e_2, e_2 \wedge e_3, e_3 \wedge e_1\}$ are a basis of 
$$ \mathbb{R}^3 \wedge \mathbb{R}^3 \simeq \mathbb{R}^3$$

Then we can compute lengths of lines this way that much is easy (or well-understood):
$$ \big|\big| a e_1 + b e_2 + c e_3 \big|\big|^2 = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$$
I am having a much harder time visualizing the wedge product version of this:
$$ \big|\big| a (e_1 \wedge e_2) + b  (e_2 \wedge e_3)  + c  (e_3 \wedge e_1)  \big|\big|^2 = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$$
It also wasn't discovered until the 20th century.  Here is an image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Sets_of_m-dimensional_objects_in_n-dimensional_space):

[image]

Comment: And what is exactly your question?

Comment: By the way, a unsung generalization of Pythagorean theorem is [De Gua's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem)